# Callback access data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a small function which checks a list of tags i submit to it and puts the good ones in a good array and the bad ones in the bad array.

This is all done within a callback so once that has been completed, the rest of my code can move on.

I am a little confused on how to access the data in my original function from the callback.

```
function findTags() {
    validateTags(tags, function () {
        //How do I access the bad array here?
        console.log('These tags are bad ' + badArray.join(','))
    });
}

//This will validate the tags submitted and strip out anything bad from them.
//We will return either success if everything is good or an array of the bad tags to fix.

function validateTags(tags, callback) {
    var badArray = new Array(),
        goodArray = new Array();
    tags = tags.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        //If the tag contains just alphanumeric, add it to the final array.
        if (tags[i].match(/^[a-z0-9\s]+$/i)) {
            goodArray.push(tags[i]);
        } else {
            //Since we didnt match an alphanumeric, add it to the bad array.
            badArray.push(tags[i]);
        }
    }
    //console.log(badArray);
    //console.log(goodArray);
    if (callback) {
        callback(badArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Just use a parameter in your callback definition -

```
validateTags(tags, function (badArray) {
    //How do I access the bad array here?
    console.log('These tags are bad ' + badArray.join(','))
});
```

In your validate tag definition, you are passing your `badArray` as an argument to your `callback` call. So, simply define a parameter to your callback definition, it will catch your array as its value.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! I figured I was kinda close